# configure service using a web interface

Tags: xml, web-applications, configuration

I have the following cenario.
I created a server component running as a service.
Now I want to build some configuration user interface.

I have seen with my nvidia firewall that they are running a apache instance and offer a full featured user interface inside my webbrowser.

If I want to do soemthing like this what technology would be fine to start with?
The server is accessible using Corba or COM.

I started thinking in designing some kind of sending some xml to the browser, let it transform the xml to an xform, get the form back and doe the configuration.

Is there some kind of framework doing those easy jobs?
What parts to use? (java, php, apache, xslt, xml)

---

I found [wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) which looks quiet usable for this kind of job. Are there other libs of this kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to my question is:

Look for things like:

- web toolkit
- web framework
- cgi
- fastcgi
- Google Web Toolkit
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look client-side XForms engines. Here's one:

https://community.emc.com/community/edn/xmltech